# Screen scraping an ASP.NET web page to retrieve data displayed in the grid view

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping

I am using RUBY to screen scrap a web page (created in asp.net) which uses gridview to display data. I am successfully able to read the data displayed on page-1 of the grid but unable to figure out how I can move to the next page in the grid to read all the data.

Problem is the page number hyperlinks are not normal hyperlinks (with URL) but instead are javascript hyperlink which causes postback to the same page..

An example of the hyperlink:-

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('gvw_offices','Page$6')" style="color:Black;">6</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using Watir, a ruby library designed for browser testing, if you're already using ruby for processing.  For one thing, it gives you a much nicer interface to the DOM elements on the page, and it makes clicking links like this easier:

```
ie.link(:text, '6').click
```

Then, of course you have easier methods for navigating the table as well.  It's easy enough to automate this process:

```
1..total_number_of_pages.each do |next_page|

  ie.link(:text, next_page).click
  # table processing goes here

end
```

I don't know your use case, but this approach has its advantages and disadvantages.  For one thing, it actually runs a browser instance, so if this is something you need to frequently run quietly in the background in completely automated way, this may not be the best approach.  On the other hand, if it's ok to launch a browser instance, then you don't have to worry about all that postback nonsense, and you can just click the link as if you were a user.

Watir: http://wtr.rubyforge.org/

Comment: I am also facing this issue.. but i am using PHP for scrapping.. so what can i do..?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to figure out the actual URL.

Option 1a: Open the page in a browser with good developer support (e.g. firefox with the web development tools) and look through the source to find where `_doPostBack` is defined.  Figure out what URL it's constructing.  Note that it might not be in the main page source, but instead in something that the page loads.

Option 1b: Ditto, but have ruby do it.  If you're fetching the page with Net:HTTP you've got the tools to find the definition of `__doPostBack` already (the body as a string, ruby's grep, and the ability to request additional files, such as those in script tags).

Option 2: Monitor the traffic between a browser and the page (e.g. with a logging proxy) to find out what the URL is.

Option 3: Ask the owner of the web page.

Option 4: Guess.  This may not be as bad as it sounds (e.g. if the original URL ends with "...?page=1" or something) but in general this is the least likely to work.

Edit (in response to your comment on the other question):

Assuming you're using the Net:HTTP library, you can do a postback by just replacing your `get` with a `post`, e.g. `my_http.post(my_url)` instead of `my_http.get(my_url)`

Edit (in response to danieltalsky's answer):

**watir** may be a really good solution for you (I'm kicking myself for not having thought of it), but be aware that you may have to [manually fire the event](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/JavaScript) or go through other hoops to get what you want.  As a specific gotcha, with any asynchronous fetch like this you need to make sure that the full response has come back before you scrape it; that isn't a problem when you're doing the request inline yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to perform the postback. The data is pass with a form POST back to the server. Like Markus said use something like FireBug or the Developer Tools in IE 8 and fiddler to watch the traffic. But honestly this is a web form using the bloated GridView and you will be in for a fun adventure. ;)

Comment: Chris:- Thanks for the reply. How do I perform the postback using ruby on that web page? Do you some examples on the net that could be of some help?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do some investigation in order to figure out what HTTP request the javascript execution is performing.  I've used the Mozilla browser with the Firebug plugin and also the  "Live HTTP Headers" plugin to help determine what is going on. It will likely become clear to you which requests you will need to make in order to traverse to the next page. Make sure you pay attention to any cookies getting set.

I've had really good success using [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) for scraping. It wraps all of the HTTP communication, html parsing and searching(using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/)), redirection, and holding onto cookies.  But it doesn't know how to execute Javascript, which is why you will need to figure out what http request to perform on your own.